# Gnuplot and unstructured data

Tags: gnuplot

I have a grid of x,y points that are (as far as gnuplot is concerned) unstructured.  I would like to plot a variable on that grid using gnuplot's pm3d.  Currently, I'm constructing a delaunay tesselation and writing each triangle into the datafile as a separate dataset.  for example, the datafile looks something like this:

```
#triangle 1
x1  y1  c1
x2  y2  c2

x3  y3  c3
x3  y3  <c1+c2+c3>/3.


#triangle 2
x1  y1  c1
x2  y2  c2

x3  y3  c3
x3  y3  <c1+c2+c3>/3.


#triangle 3
...
```

This seems to work Ok, but I was wondering if there a better way to accomplish this?  (if it matters, I'm using Python+Delny interface to construct the delaunay tesselation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the above solution is as good as I'm going to find. If you have a better way to plot unstructured data in gnuplot, other than `dgrid3d`, I'd love to hear it!