# GNUPlot: From 3D scatter plot to Countour map

Tags: c#, wifi, gnuplot, interpolation

Given the following list of `x,y,z` points (`z` is actually a signal strength indicator in dBm):

```
63  371 -21
142 371 -9
233 374 -18
288 371 -36
310 373 -38
349 374 -39
415 348 -44
507 334 -49
689 337 -56
635 254 -57
422 284 -42
380 278 -39
281 280 -39
214 299 -34
146 285 -30
81  302 -39
76  246 -39
80  214 -44
137 200 -44
64  134 -48
73  87  -48
200 101 -46
230 202 -44
246 105 -53
285 109 -53
278 191 -50
334 87  -54
395 189 -56
513 208 -58
510 99  -61
553 101 -62
593 100 -65
634 101 -64
679 102 -68
731 196 -70
```

I can quite easily generate a 3D scatter plot using this command in gnuplot:

`splot "C:/path/to/points.dat" with points`

What I'm really after is a way to "fill in the gaps" and create a surface. The ultimate goal is to use data like the points shown above to generate an RF map for a given WiFi access point. The resulting map would be used to calculate the possible locations of a device, given its RSSI (received signal strength indicator).

(Several APs and their associated RF maps will be used, however I don't think the specifics are relevant to this question.)

What would be the best way to interpolate the z-values (RSSI in dBm, in this case) for the remaining points?

**EDIT :**

I seem to have made some progress. Using `set dgrid3d 50,100 splines` before the `splot` command *seems* to generate more or less what I'm looking for. So the next question is: how can I replicate this kind of function in code (C#, ideally)?

Comment: `dgrid3d` is simply an interface to different interpolation routines that interpolate your scattered data onto a regular grid.  The default used by gnuplot is inverse-distance weighting.  You could easily get an algorithm for it off of Wikipedia.  `splines` is a little more tricky and uses "thin plate splines".  I don't know anything about that, but you could google around to try to figure it out.

Comment: Alternatively, I once asked about plotting unstructured data using gnuplot for colormap plots.  The solution that I came up with is documented [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9702075/748858).

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot @mgilson. I asked around on math.stackexchange as well and they suggested Delaunay triangulation. Once I've got some working code I'll post my solution here.

Comment: Aaaand I just noticed that your solution involved Delaunay as well! Seems to be the best way to go for my needs. Cheers!

Comment: Yeah, at one point I though about proposing that gnuplot add something new to the `splot` command.  e.g. `splot 'datafile' u 1:2:3 w delaunay` instead of `w pm3d`.